# How to add parents to tasks in TFS using Excel macro

Tags: excel, tfs-sdk, vba

I have an excel macro, which is supposed to do the following:

1. Import a PBI from TFS.
2. Add tasks to the PBI.
3. Upload the tasks back to TFS.

The macro works fine except I am having trouble adding the PBI as a parent for the tasks. I am trying to use the Links and Attachments option of the menu to add the link because Microsoft doesn't have an API for the TFS Excel Add-In.

After searching, I have found the Microsoft documentation about the Links and Attachments button is minimal at best. Here is what I am trying.

```
Dim publishControl As CommandBarControl
Dim wiStore
Set publishControl = FindTeamControl("IDC_LINKS_ATTACHMENTS")
Set wiStore = FindTeamControl("IDC_IMPORT")
publishControl.Parent = wiStore.GetWorkItem(207895)
```

I'm essentially looking for documentation on
`FindTeamControl("IDC_LINKS_ATTACHMENTS")` and `FindTeamControl("IDC_IMPORT")`.

Comment: does it have to be through Excel? this is so much easier using the Client Object Model, the REST Api or Powershell...

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. I have non-technical users who are creating tasks in separate excel tabs those are being uploaded to TFS. I also do not have time to rewrite the whole thing right now somewhere else. But, point taken for future efforts.

Comment: I don't think the excel add-in was ever meant to be extensible or reusable. As far as I know there is no documentation on it whatsoever. If you're in vsto you could always invoke the client object model yourself...

Comment: That explains why I had so much difficulty trying to find documentation. Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use queries to find links between work items. A condition in the Where clause may apply to the links or to any work item that is the source or the target of a link.

[Source].[FieldName] = Value

[Target].[FieldName] = Value

[System.Links.LinkType] = 'LinkName'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130306.aspx